# How to hide other tabs content and display only selected tabs content with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

As you can see in HTML, there is six buttons which need to work as tab switcher buttons. Selected button must have additional class "current" so I can style current button (for example - current tab button class should be "buttons-regular-current").

Also I don't really know how to make these tabs work. I know I need to use JS/JQuery but don't have much experience with these things.

Information from "featured-table" div class should be non-hided by default and when I click on "Tab 1" button, information should change with information from "container-table-1" div container etc.

I am sorry for my bad english but I hope you will understand. :)

My HTML:

```html
<div class="tabs-button-container">
  <div class="tabs-title">
    <h2>Block Title</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="buttons-featured"><a href="#">Featured Tab</a></div>
    <div class="buttons-regular"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></div>
    <div class="buttons-regular"><a href="#">Tab 2</a></div>
    <div class="buttons-regular"><a href="#">Tab 3</a></div>
    <div class="buttons-regular"><a href="#">Tab 4</a></div>
    <div class="buttons-regular"><a href="#">Tab 5</a></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="featured-table">
  <p>Tab content</p>
</div>
<div class="container-table-1" style="display:none">
  <p>Tab content</p>
</div>
<div class="container-table-2" style="display:none">
  <p>Tab content</p>
</div>
<div class="container-table-3" style="display:none">
  <p>Tab content</p>
</div>
<div class="container-table-4" style="display:none">
  <p>Tab content</p>
</div>
<div class="container-table-5" style="display:none">
  <p>Tab content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `data` attributes.

You could edit your tabs like so:

```
<div class="buttons">
  <div data-tabid="f" class="tab buttons-featured"><a href="#">Featured Tab</a></div>
  <div data-tabid="1" class="tab buttons-regular"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></div>
  <div data-tabid="2" class="tab buttons-regular"><a href="#">Tab 2</a></div>
  <div data-tabid="3" class="tab buttons-regular"><a href="#">Tab 3</a></div>
  <div data-tabid="4" class="tab buttons-regular"><a href="#">Tab 4</a></div>
  <div data-tabid="5" class="tab buttons-regular"><a href="#">Tab 5</a></div>
</div>
```

This adds the `data` attributes which will act as an identifier to the tab. Also the class `tab` has been added to allow us to grab the tab in jQuery.

Next change your containers to match the `data` attributes in the tabs

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="featured-table" data-blockid="f">
    <p>Tab content f</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container-table-1" data-blockid="1" style="display:none">
    <p>Tab content 1</p>
  </div> 
  <div class="container-table-2" data-blockid="2" style="display:none">
    <p>Tab content 2</p>
  </div> 
  <!-- and so on -->
</div>
```

*Note that I have added a wrapper* `div` *around the containers*

Now using jQuery

```
$('.tab').click(function(){
  var tabID = $(this).data('tabid'); // Get the tab ID data attribute

  // Remove all instances of "current" class from tabs
  $('.buttons').children().removeClass('current');

  // Add "current" class to selected tab
  $(this).addClass('current');

  // Hide all elements under the wrapper class
  // Same thing can be achieved with .children().css("display", "none");
  $('.wrapper').children().hide(); 

  // Show the container using the data attribute "blockid" as a selector
  // Again same thing with .find("[data-blockid="+tabID+"]").css("display", "block");
  $('.wrapper').find("[data-blockid="+tabID+"]").show();
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xfcdfho7/)

Comment: Thanks, your answer was most helpful because it resolved all my questions.

Answer (score 3):

Four ways to hide and show:

```
$(element).fadeIn(200)
$(element).fadeOut(200)

$(element).show()
$(element).hide()

$(element).css('display', 'block')
$(element).css('display', 'none')

$(element).removeClass('hide').addClass('show')
$(element).removeClass('show').addClass('hide')
```

Thus:

```
// If a button is clicked
$(".buttons-regular").click(function()
{
     // Would require needing to hide all others
     //check which button was clicked via $(this)
     if($(this).text() == "Tab 1")
          // Show content
          $('.container-table-1').fadeIn(200);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class name in `container-table` so you can handle it later like

```
...
<div class="tab container-table-3" style="display:none">
  <p>Tab content</p>
</div>
<div class="tab container-table-4" style="display:none">
  <p>Tab content</p>
</div>
<div class="tab container-table-5" style="display:none">
  <p>Tab content</p>
</div>
```

And then, when button clicked, execute this script: `$(".tab").css("display", "none")`. And show the div what you are going to show with `$(SOME_CLASS).css("display", "block)`.

You also can do similar in buttons too so you can make a clicked effect or something else. Maybe you can use `addClass()` or `removeClass()` method for buttons.

https://jsfiddle.net/h213ue65/1/ Check out in jsfiddle!

Comment: Should mention that this example doesn't work for the "featured" tab / container... not sure if that's what you wanted

Comment: Yes, after switching to another tab I cannot return to "featured" tab. Also, it would be great if you could add some more functionality to add class to active button so I can style these buttons after. :)